# MODX revo как передать файл с формы через phpmailer

Tags: php, modx

Собственно есть сайт на MODX revo. Есть форма с которой пользователь может отправлять помимо своих данных еще и файл. Т.е что-то типа

```js
<script>
  $("#main-pofo").submit(function() {
    var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/assets/php/phone.php",
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            $(th).find(".success").addClass("active").fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(th).find(".success").removeClass("active").fadeOut();
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form id="main-pofo" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="file" name="file">
</form>


//собственно сам файл phone.php
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['user_mail'];
$message = $_POST['user_msg'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = '********';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = '********';
    $mail->Password   = '*******';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom(********);
    $mail->addAddress(*******);
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'С сайта ******';
    $mail->Body    = "<br><b>ФИО или организация:</b>$name<br><b>Email:</b>$email<br><b>Телефон:</b>$phone <br><b>Сообщение:</b>$message";
    $mail->AltBody = 'Что-то пошло не так и поэтому здесь этот текст';

?>
```

Форма для примера просто. Файл не передается. Что сделать и как исправить?

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что у вас не передается файл вместе с остальными параметрами формы в ajax-запросе? Может переформулируете Ваш вопрос, раз проблема  не связана напрямую с php/modX/phpMail? Тогда больше участников смогут Вам помочь советом.

Comment: Да, спасибо, вы правы файл просто не передавался. Добавил
`var formData =$(".popup-form").submit(function(e){
            return ;
        });
        var formData = new FormData(formData[0]);`

И поставил data: formData. Так что вопрос решен.